# Как определить что строка состоит только из пробелов

Tags: javascript

Есть некая структура

```
<div class="level">
    <div class="block">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

У меня есть объект lvl в котором хранится div с классом level. Так вот как определить что внутри никаких символов кроме пробелов нет (этих символов может быть сколько угодно)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var string = document.querySelector( 'div.level>div.block' ).textContent;

function isNonBreakingSpace( character ) {
    return character == '\u00A0';
}

var result = Array.prototype.every.call( string, isNonBreakingSpace );
```

Comment: isNonBreakingSpace интуитивние trim()

Comment: @Gorets, `isWhitespace` если достраивать до общего решения. `trim`, кстати, будет лишнюю работу делать и надо бы проверить, может ли она в Уникод...

Answer (score 1):

```
lvl.textContent.match(/^\s*$/);
```